# Powershell create shortcut with Drive as variable

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

Good evening everybody,

i'm trying the first script, it works perfectly when i hard code C: or D:

This is OK :

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Alarm\Respus Monitor.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = '"C:\Alarm\RespusMonitorRT.exe"'
$Shortcut.Arguments = "Profile=VoIP"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = '"C:\Alarm"'
$Shortcut.Save()
```

but when i'm trying to use a $drive Variable to define the map drive, it doesn't work, shortcut is not ok, the next script is not ok with varaible. It creates the shortcut, but the shortcut is going on "This computer" instead the good software. WorkingDirectory is ok but not the TargetPath

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($drive + "\Alarm\Respus Monitor.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $drive + '"\Alarm\RespusMonitorRT.exe"'
$Shortcut.Arguments = "Profile=VoIP"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $drive + '\Alarm'
$Shortcut.Save()
```

thanks for help !

create the shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly why but it seems like powershell is not to fund of calculating the string you would like in your .TargetPath in one go

If you enclose it in () then it will calculate the string correctly so it looks like this:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($drive + "\Alarm\Respus Monitor.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = ($drive + '"\Alarm\RespusMonitorRT.exe"')
$Shortcut.Arguments = "Profile=VoIP"
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $drive + '\Alarm'
$Shortcut.Save()
```